# Android Java : What happens in an AsyncTask with more than one task being operated?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I have two tasks I'd like to do in the background, but I figured it could be good to do them both in the background and return a map when done.

But my problem is I think one of them is not being processed, or at least I'm not sure if they should be both put in there.

My code is as follows.

```
  final TextView         v = (TextView) P.findViewById(R.id.abbr);
  final SimpleDraweeView i = (SimpleDraweeView) P.findViewById(R.id.icon);
  new AsyncTask<Object, Object, HashMap<String, Object>>() {
     @Override
     protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String   k = SyncProfiles.getIcon(A, C.getNumber());
        Drawable dr;
        if (k == null) {
           dr = H.setDrawableColor(A, R.drawable.contact_user_bg, H.aoRandColor());
        } else {
           dr = null;
        }
        HashMap<String, Object> r = new HashMap<>();
        r.put("bg", dr);
        r.put("url", Images.ImageServerResize(k, 180));
        return r;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> o) {
        v.setText(C.getName().trim().substring(0, 1));
        if (o.get("url") == null) {
           contact_bg.setBackground((Drawable) o.get("bg"));
           i.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
          i.setImageURI(Uri.parse((String) o.get("url")));
          i.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
     }
  }.execute();
```

Comment: Where is second `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, it's one `AsyncTask`, I want to do two operations inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call AsyncTask.execute() more than once on a same instance.

```
// For example
SampleTask  sampleTask = new SampleTask();  
sampleTask.execute();  
sampleTask.execute(); //Error, IllegalStateException
```